# Get number from thousands place with JS

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get the second number from the left.

If I have a given string of `98765`.

If I wanted to get `9`, I would do:

```
Math.floor(98765/10000);
```

If I wanted to get `8`, It would make sense to do:

```
Math.floor(98765/1000);
```

However; it returns `98`

Do you know how I would get number `8`?  (Possibly w/ modulus)

-- Keep in mind the given number is completely random. **It can be between 0-1000000**.

```
        var num = 98765; // Number

        var digit = Math.floor(num % 10),
            digitsValue,

            tens = Math.floor(num/10 % 10),
            tensValue,

            hundreds = Math.floor(num/100 % 10),
            hundredsValue,

            thousands = Math.floor(num/1000),
            thousandsValue,

            tenThousands = Math.floor(num/10000),
            tenThousandsValue,

            hundredThousands = Math.floor(num/100000),
            hundredThousandsValue,

            millions = Math.floor(num/1000000),
            millionsValue;
```

The above code is good, except that if `num` has a length of 5, `thousandsValue` returns `undefined`; however, if `num` has a length less than 5, it returns correctly.

Comment: How about using bracket notation to access by index?

Comment: Below in Sam's answer, you said you're looking for each of the places? In your question above, you said you're only looking for the second. Tell us exactly what you hope to accomplish. If you want to separate the number into each decimal place, you can still use Sam's method.

Comment: I'm trying to find placement values of a number all the way to the millions place.

Comment: Given the specific input of `12345678` (or any other arbitrary *but clearly-specified* input) what *specific output* do you expect?

Comment: @blgt figured it out.  Math.floor( (num % 10000) / 1000 );

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Math.floor( (98765 % 10000) / 1000 )`

Answer (score 2):

use strings? easier. you can turn the string back into an integer too

```
var number = 98765;
var myEight = number.toString()[1];
```

edit: http://jsfiddle.net/Swgk6/

Comment: I forgot to mention the number can be between 0 to 9 trillion. Math.floor(98765/1000); would work for a number with a length of four, but not five!

Comment: this technique would work for any integer. edit: I should say, any integer that a javascript variable can hold

Comment: If you cast it to a string, the size of your number doesn't matter at all. His method will always get just the second character of whatever number you have.

Comment: I'm trying to get decimal places of a random string.  Like the ones, tens, hundreds, thousands, ten thousands.  I ran into a problem when a random string (lets say "99999") was given, the thousands (thousands = Math.floor(num/1000);) return "undefined"

Comment: well you can't use `Math.floor` on a string

Comment: It wasn't a string.  It return the value of an input field.

Comment: @Matthew If you go this way you can also get the 4th position by counting backwards from the end: `parseInt(number.toString().charAt(number.toString().length - 4))`